# organizar GUI para qualquer tamanho de tela no Unity5

Tags: unity-5

Estou criando um projeto 3d, fazendo um menu. 
Quando eu rodo o jogo em resoluções diferentes sempre muda os menus.
Eu faço tudo em `Free aspect`, minha intenção é que mesmo em outras resoluções o menu e seus botoes permaneça iguais.

Eu tenho feito com `gui.Skyn`, minhas medidas são baseadas dessa forma :

```
 posiY = Screen.height/2 + (Screen.height/2-93);
 posiX = Screen.width/2 -(Screen.width/18-20);
 function OnGUI(){    
GUI.skin.font = fonte;   
GUI.skin.label.fontSize = Screen.height/10;                                                if(colocarItem.exibeMenu){      
GUI.skin = perSkin[1];           
if (GUI.Button(Rect( posiX2  ,posiY2  ,Screen.width/12 -5 ,Screen.height/6),"")
     {

     }     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Diogo, bom a duas opções para você resolver este problema, uma que eu usava antigamente antes da nova UI da Unity o Famoso "Canvas".

1º A primeira solução é vc usar sua equação baseada em "%", um exemplo , primeiro de tudo padronize seu Câmera Ratio, faça o jogo em 16:9 ou 16:10, depois disso você tem que fazer os cálculos de suas posições sempre em %.

- No seu caso sempre há essa variação por causa que você usa pixel exatos, como provavelmente você não trava uma resolução fixa dentro do seu jogo, isso muda conforme a resolução escolhida pelo usuário.

Exemplo de Código Utilizando GameObject como GUI:

```
void Start () 
{
    GameObject.Find("QualquerObjeto").transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint ( new Vector3 ( (Screen.width * 20) / 100, Screen.height * 90 / 100 , 10 ) );
}
```

Esse pequeno Trecho de código tem a função de sempre no start ajustar esse objeto em 20% da tela em X e 90% da tela em Y, ou seja não importa a resolução ele sempre vai ficar (20% em X e 90% em Y)... tente fazer a mesma coisa em seu GUI *camera.ScreenToWorldPoint* (transforma a posição de espaço de tela(pixel) para o espaço mundo(produto escalar)). Não será necessário usar isso já que está usando GUI

2º Esse eu acho bem mais simples, é utilizar a nova GUI da Unity o Canvas, como é complexo e muita coisa para explicar vou te passar um link de tutorial que pode te facilitar a usar.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVFqnDNq84w

Comment: Opa muito obrigado, a solução pra isso foi realmente o Canvas, ele facilita o trabalho, para quem tem este problema sugiro que use o Canvas tbm.